# Distributed Computing: Asynchronous Receive

Tags: distributed-computing

If I have a receive primitive where I simply receive a message from a specified sender and I have a receive-all primitive where I receive from any sender, how can this be extended for real-time applications?

This is a question in some course notes I have that I never noticed before :).  Any ideas?

An asynchronous receive is a non-blocking receive.

My idea is that we can somehow poll the sender every now and again to check that no messages are getting lost??... I'm not sure.  Any ideas welcomed :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is to use timeouts: Messages can be lost in asynchronous communication so if we are left waiting on a message for too long then we should request to have it resent; a timeout can be used to achieve this.